# Placing a Device in EAGLE

Tags: eaglecad, packages

I just added a new library (the adafruit library) in EAGLE comprised of many devices and packages.  I can place packages, but not devices (usually devices represent a few different specific packages).

I'm using EAGLE-6.2.0.  How do I get the devices onto a board?

Comment: In the schematic you put the symbols, and in the layour you have the packages

Comment: Apparently OP read the answer and was off. Didn't return here, so it looks like his problem is solved. He *might* at least have accepted it. Very uncivilized.

Comment: Yup, he was last here 5 hours after the first and only answer.  Looks like another drive-by poster.

Answer (score 1):

You can only select different packages for a device, when the author of the library provided these. Take for example the ATMEGA32U2 in the adafruit library. This device has only one package (TQFP32-08). The ATTINY10 device on the other side provides two packages (SOT23-6 and UDFN-8).

When you find a device that has not the package you need, you can create your own. Create a new library and reuse the symbol of the device. Various package formats are in the ref-packages.lbr library. The final thing to do now is to connect the *right* pins of the symbol with the pins of the package.